# Redirect Apache to Tomcat on Vesta CP

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, nginx, vesta

I have a VPS server with Ubuntu 18 O.S. In this VPS I have installed VESTA CP, which comes with Apache 2 and Nginx. After that I have intalled Tomcat 9(port 8082) to serve a Java Spring based webapp.
If I enter the address "serverIP:8082/AppFolder" I can access the app, but I want to redirect the apache server to the tomcat one, so I can write the domain name and load the webapp.

I have tried .htaccess file but it shows an apache error page. I have no permission to view this file is the message.

What can I do to solve this?

-Nginx config:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://IP:8080;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
        root           /home/admin/web/webapp.com/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/webapp.com.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/apache2/domains/webapp.com.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/webapp.com/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      http://IP:8080;
}
```

-Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost IP:8080>

    ServerName webapp.com
    ServerAlias www.webapp.com
    ServerAdmin info@webapp.com
    DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/webapp.com/public_html    
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/webapp.com/cgi-bin/
    Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/webapp.com/stats/
    Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/webapp.com/document_errors/
    #SuexecUserGroup admin admin
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/webapp.com.bytes bytes
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domains/webapp.com.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domains/webapp.com.error.log
    <Directory /home/admin/web/webapp.com/public_html>
        AllowOverride All
        Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
        php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/webapp.com/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
        php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/admin/web/webapp.com/stats>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
        RMode config
        RUidGid admin admin
        RGroups www-data
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule itk.c>
        AssignUserID admin admin
    </IfModule>

    IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/apache2.webapp.com.conf*

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have found an answer...editing the config file of nginx:

```
proxy_pass      http://IP:8082; <--TOMCAT PORT
root           /home/admin/web/webapp.com/public_html; <--JSP PAGES PATH
```

Default config file has the Apache port and apache html pages path.
I suppose this can be done using apache proxy_mod, but I don´t know which way is better...if anyone can explain the two ways(via apache or via nginx) I apreciate it.